# factors to be considered when choosing a free library in any technology

Tags: libraries

I was going through these links in stackoverflow.com

Free java libraries,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries

Free .net libraries,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries

I know there are 'n' number of free libraries in every technology..

- what are the factors to be considered when choosing a free library in any technology?
- How would you choose a free library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it maintained?
- Can I get the source?
- Is there the option to pay for
  support?
- Can I find evidence of satisfied
  users?

Answer (score 1):

Licensing is the big one for me, as most projects I work on are closed-source bespoke software. GPL is immediately a no, as are libraries which require me to show a popup "thanks to l77tHorse for use of his 'Suxor' code".